# Not able to set status bar background in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono

I need to change status bar UI, where background is black and text colour is white, in Xamarin.iOS (not forms).
For that I wanted to customise the status bar view, in have searched all I could on the internet and found below code working for majority of the people.

```
var statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
//tried with key statusBarWindow.statusBar as well.
statusBar.BackgroundColor = ...;
```

Above code crashes in Xamarin.iOS (tested on iPhone Xs Simulator).
Here is the log of the crash.

at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at Foundation.NSObject.ValueForKey (Foundation.NSString key) [0x0001c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject.g.cs:599

Could anyone help me with any hint as to why this code crashes in Xamarin.
I tried finding the cause on this GitHub thread https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000/issues/597

But here also I am not able to get any clue of it.
Also, if there is any other way to customise the status bar I would like to drop this idea and go ahead with proposed one.

[image: Refer here]

Answer (score 0):

From what I know this works but usually when I use this I always make a check if the selector is available or not using `RespondsToSelector`:

```
UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
{
    statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
}
```

Also, do not forget to add the style to info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
```

**Update**

Use the above code in `AppDelegate.cs` in the `FinishedLaunching` method.

Comment: I have updated the question which has your code, no avail

Comment: Although this code does not crash when put in AppDelegate.cs, but I need to customise status bar view for every controller, how do we achieve it?

Comment: You want this to be different on different controller's is it?

Comment: But that is odd why do you want to change the status bar color to different colors on different pages?

Comment: Actually we have landing page, where status bar is supposed to be default one, when we click a table cell on landing page, we go to detail page on detail page, the UI given to me as such, where background should be black, all texts and icon should be white on it.

so pretty much I need to at least two customisation, one for main page and one for detail one